# Open Cash Drawer Connected to a USB port

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code to open a cash drawer using lpt and com port.

```
    Dim intFileNo As Integer = FreeFile()

    FileOpen(1, "c:\escapes.txt", OpenMode.Output)
    PrintLine(1, Chr(27) & "p" & Chr(0) & Chr(25) & Chr(250))
    FileClose(1)

    Shell("print /d:com1 c:\escapes.txt", vbNormalFocus)
```

The above code works great. However, one of my client is using a USB.

Anyone know of any code to open cash drawer using USB port?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried searching for the manufacturer's spec?

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember some of the USB cash drawers will need to be opened by setting a memory location to a specific value. It's all down to the driver required for the cash drawer so you'll have to acquire the manufacturer's specifications.

Telling us which brand of cash drawer would be a big first step.

Addendum: After some searching I've turned up the following useful links.

A proper answer is really too big and time consuming to fit in here and will demand a bit of experimentation to get it working but basically you can install a USB to COM driver from Prolific and then write software to that or rework the VB6 answer you linked into VB.NET using the usual techniques.

http://www.jack-frost.co.uk/vb6_usb_cash_drawer.html

http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/index.aspx

http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/27/ldi-C4141_USB_InstallationGuide.pdf

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/prolific-pl2303-usb-to-serial-port-adapter-driver/1902e9e0-4af0-4f36-84bc-f487d4022f1f

http://edvoncken.net/2010/08/pl-2303-usb-to-serial-driver/

Comment: The brand name is "posiedon" and the kick command is "<27><112><0><100><250>". I successfully open the cash drawer using the vb6 code from [http://www.jack-frost.co.uk/vb6_usb_cash_drawer.html](http://www.jack-frost.co.uk/vb6_usb_cash_drawer.html) but I want a VB.NET version.

Comment: Well you'll have to either update that code to VB.NET or write a little COM wrapper for it. That's really beyond the scope of this question though